# How to refer to an array by Uri in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, uri

Programming my application would be a lot easier if I could refer to an array by URI, and use that array to inflate a list. Has anyone done this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by refer to it? Try to be more specific about what you are trying to do

Comment: So, say you are using an array XML file to populate a list. The regular way is to refer to the resource, R.array.thearray. However, I want to refer to the same array with a URI. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to refer to an array using a `Uri` in the same way that you do using `R.array.yourarray`.

Technically, just to say the proper answer, you could wrap an object to parse the `Uri` for you and return the `R.array.yourarray` for you. Like a Content Provider, for example. But obviously that is just nonsense, there is no reason to create a non standard thing when the standard works just fine.

I don't think there is any scenario that would require a Uri that the standard way doesn't handle just fine.